# Amazon SES not delivering to fresh g suite address

Tags: amazon-ses, google-workspace

Amazon gives 'Delivery Status Notification (Failure)'.

Important information:
the gsuite recipient didn't exist when the first 5-ish emails where sent.
The gsuite destination domain is mine, we're using ses to do automated mailings to our own students. Some users didn't get created automatically but were targeted by SES regardless.

However, even once the recipient is created, the problem remains. Same error.

Sending to recipient+blabla@gsuite works. So I'm assuming SES decides not to send to recipients that failed too many times?

If this is the case, is there a way to tell SES to retry anyway?

And no, I didn't ask amazon, apparently you need to pay for a support subscription before they're willing to help...

Thanks in advance,

Wim

Comment: Have you checked the suppression list?

Comment: I have, it didn't help. Unless there's a delay of some sort for ithe changes to take hold? The feedback notification email also doesn't mention the suppression list or any kind of diagnostic code...

Answer (score 0):

Update:

There is also an account level suppression list ( [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-suppression-list.html] ). I checked the 'global' suppression list before, which didn't help.

Why all of this information is this hard to find is beyond me. Or maybe it's just me '-)

Extra note for people fighting with aws cli: before you can list the suppressed addresses or remove them you first have to 'turn on' the management of the list:

aws sesv2 put-account-suppression-attributes --suppressed-reasons BOUNCE COMPLAINT

Hope this helps someone else...